# Copy mails from local folder to public/shared folder

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2013

This Outlook macro is supposed to, when the local folder has 5 emails, ask the user to move them to a public shared folder and delete the original 5 emails.

I keep getting this "Operation failed" error message on the line below.

```
 **Set NewFolder = myFolder.CopyTo(PblcSharedFolder)**
```

From comment: This line is meant to copy the entire folder of five emails.

```
Sub MoveEmail()
    Dim app As New Outlook.Application
    Dim nameSpace As Outlook.nameSpace
    Dim currentExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim currentSelection As Outlook.selection
    Dim currentMailItem As MailItem
    Dim emailCopy As MailItem
    Dim myFolder
    Dim PblcSharedFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim NewFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim folderName
    Dim mailboxNameString
    Dim result

    folderName = "Local Folder"
    mailboxNameString = "My Inbox Name"
    Set nameSpace = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set currentExplorer = app.ActiveExplorer
    Set currentSelection = currentExplorer.selection
    Set myFolder = nameSpace.Folders(mailboxNameString).Folders("Inbox").Folders(folderName)

    If (myFolder.Items.Count = 5) Then
        result = MsgBox("Would you like to move the content of your Local folder to the Public-shared Folder?", vbYesNo)

        If result = vbYes Then

            Set PblcSharedFolder = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders)
            Set PblcSharedFolder = PblcSharedFolder.Folders("Subfolder")
            Set PblcSharedFolder = PblcSharedFolder.Folders("Public Shared Folder")

            Set NewFolder = myFolder.CopyTo(PblcSharedFolder)

            NewFolder.Name = "_" & nameSpace.CurrentUser.Name & " " & Now

            For i = myFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
                myFolder.Items(i).Delete
            Next i

        Else

            Stop

        End If
    End If

    For i = 1 To currentSelection.Count
       Set currentMailItem = currentSelection.Item(i)
       Debug.Print "[" & Date & " " & Time & "] moving #" & m & _
                   ": xfolder = " & folderName & _
                   "; subject = " & currentMailItem.Subject & "..."
       currentMailItem.To = nameSpace.CurrentUser.Name
       currentMailItem.Move myFolder
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

untested!

```
If result = vbYes Then

        Set PblcSharedFolder = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders)
        Set PblcSharedFolder = PblcSharedFolder.Folders("Subfolder")
        Set PblcSharedFolder = PblcSharedFolder.Folders("Public Shared Folder")
        Dim myCopiedItem As Outlook.MailItem 


        For i = myFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set myCopiedItem = myFolder.Items(i).Copy 
            myCopiedItem.Move PblcSharedFolder 
            myFolder.Items(i).Delete
        Next i
    Else
        Stop
    End If
```

I did to be honest not quite unterstand what this line is for:

```
    NewFolder.Name = "_" & nameSpace.CurrentUser.Name & " " & Now
```

Comment: so that after copying the folder into the public/shared folder it changes the folder name as the CurrentUser's name  and date.

Comment: I am trying to copy the entire folder, not just the emails.